# Testing that static method inside void method has been called once

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I need some help with testing. Having the following method:

```
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Tag tag) {

        if (tagService.listUserTags(tag.getUser())
                .size() > Constants.Tags.maxPerUser) {
            TaskUtils.createTask(url, param);
        }
    }
```

I want to test that TaskUtils.createTask() is called once, but I don't want the code inside it to be executed. I have tried like this:

```
        @Test
        @PrepareForTest(TaskUtils.class)
        public void testPrePersistMethodWhenTagCountOverLimit() {
            [...]
            when(tags.size()).thenReturn(Constants.Tags.maxPerUser + 1);
            when (tagService.listUserTags(tag.getUser())).thenReturn(tags);

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(TaskUtils.class);
            PowerMockito.doNothing().when(TaskUtils.class, "createTask", Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(String.class));                                            

            Method method = ClassUtils.getMethodWithAnnotation(TagListener.class, PrePersist.class);
            method.invoke(tagListener, tag); //here the prePersist method is called

            PowerMockito.verifyStatic( Mockito.times(1));

        }
```

But the method TaskUtils.createTask() is actually executed in spite of doNothing. 
Part of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fi.util.TaskUtils.createTask(TaskUtils.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:753)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:106)
    at fi.intra.test.domain.listener.TestTagListener.testPrePersistMethodWhenTagCountOverLimit(TestTagListener.java:92)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is the type of both the arguments url and param String?

Comment: @pvpkiran, yes it is

Comment: I assume you have this `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`. Rest of the code looks fine

Comment: Yes, I have @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Comment: if you know the exact parameter being passed as url and param in your test class, then try to use that directly instead of Mockito.any(String.class).

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried that, but it still enters the method and tries to execute what's inside

Comment: Not sure if it helps but instead of  
`Method method = ClassUtils.getMethodWithAnnotation(TagListener.class, PrePersist.class);
            method.invoke(tagListener, tag);` you can do like this `Whitebox.invokeMethod(tagListener, "prePersist", tag);`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that, unfortunately, it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works and should be equivalent to your case:

I used Gradle for building, and added the following dependency:

`testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-mockito-release-full', version: '1.6.4'`

**The test**

```
package sojava.mocking;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyData.class)
public class PowerMockitoTests {

    @Test
    public void static_method_when_mocked_does_nothing() throws Exception {
        int amount = 123;

        // Arrange
        mockStatic(MyData.class);
        doNothing().when(MyData.class, "increment", amount);

        // Action
        new MyDataWrapper().increment(amount);
        verifyStatic(times(1));
        MyData.increment(amount);

        // Assert
        assertThat(MyData.getCount()).isEqualTo(0);
    }
}
```

Have you seen this code?

```
new MyDataWrapper().increment(amount);
verifyStatic(times(1));
MyData.increment(amount);
```

This is awkward but this is how it works. Want to test that a static method was called a number of times? Then you call that method, then call `verifyStatic()`, then call that static method again. The last call will trigger the check.

**Class using the static method**

```
package sojava.mocking;

public class MyDataWrapper {
    public void increment(int amount) {
        MyData.increment(amount);
    }
}
```

**Class containing the static method**

package sojava.mocking;

```
public class MyData {

    private static int count = 0;

    private MyData() {
    }

    public static void increment(int amount) {
        count += amount;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

**More samples:** more samples are located on their [Github page on the `tests` folder](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/blob/master/tests/mockito/junit4/src/test/java/samples/powermockito/junit4/staticmocking/MockStaticTest.java).